# How to Remove Bullets from Widgets in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i´m having some difficulty applying style override to all widgets in my wordpress theme. I created the theme from scratch, so I have absolutely NO IDEA how they got these bullets got there.

I want to remove the bullets from items in the lists. The html is:

```
<li id="categories-3" class="widget widget_categories"><h2 class="widgettitle">Categories</h2>
        <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/big-notch-updates/" title="View all posts filed under Big Notch Updates">Big Notch Updates</a> (20)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/music_news/" title="View all posts filed under Music News">Music News</a> (50)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/ramblings/" title="View all posts filed under Ramblings">Ramblings</a> (43)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/site-news/" title="View all posts filed under Site News">Site News</a> (14)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/stuff-i-like/" title="View all posts filed under Stuff I Like">Stuff I Like</a> (25)
</li>
        </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

This is the code I came up with so far that doesn't seem to be working:

```
li#categoryposts-3 li.cat-item {list-style: none;}
```

I have no idea what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li.widget ul,
li.widget li { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: It's likely not working in your code because your ID names don't match. `"categories-3" != "categoryposts-3"`

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
li#categories-3 {background-image: none; list-style: none;}
li#categories-3 li.cat-item {background-image: none; list-style: none;}
```

1. There is a wrong id
2. You need two styles

Answer (score 0):

```
#categoryposts-3 ul {
    background-image: none; list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the !important keyword in your css, like this:

```
li{
list-style:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below removes the bullets from a list.

```html
<li style="list-style: none;" class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/big-notch-updates/" title="View all posts filed under Big Notch Updates">Big Notch Updates</a> (20)
</li>
<li style="list-style: none;" class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/music_news/" title="View all posts filed under Music News">Music News</a> (50)
</li>
<li style="list-style: none;" class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/ramblings/" title="View all posts filed under Ramblings">Ramblings</a> (43)
</li>
    <li style="list-style: none;" class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/site-news/" title="View all posts filed under Site News">Site News</a> (14)
</li>
    <li style="list-style: none;" class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://www.bignotch.com/category/stuff-i-like/" title="View all posts filed under Stuff I Like">Stuff I Like</a> (25)
</li>
```